# Fail to create image with Bitmap ImageView Java

Tags: java, android, image, bluetooth, bitmap

I have a piece of code that receives Bytearrays via bluetooth with Python.
The data sent is an array of a 10x10 jpg of the color orange BGR=[0,106,254].
Im trying to display the image in Android Studio using this code:

'''

```
private void readImage(byte[] readBuf) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        //BufferedInputStream = readBuf;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PiCam);
        String s = new String(readBuf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] x = Base64.decode(s, Base64.DEFAULT);  //convert from base64 to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(x, 0, x.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        System.out.println(x);
    }
 }
```

'''

System.out.println(x) gives me [B@31b9d31 and [B@18d0c16, so these are the byte arrays that are decoded by decodeByteArray.

I think that the following message means that the bitmap can't be displayed by ImageView.
Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

When I i print bitmap, it gives 'null', so perhaps the decoding failed?

My goal is to send an image, to decode it and to display it.
Let me know if I could provide any more details.

Comment: `The data sent is an array of a 10x10 jpg of ....`  Do you mean a .jpg file is sent. And the .jpg file has a resolution of 10x10 pixels?

Comment: Further: as you try to base 64 decode the buffer the data should have been sent base64 encoded. You did not tell that.

Comment: To summarize: It's pretty unclear what you actually send. Also: what does all have to do with javascript?

Comment: System.out.println(s); Try and tell what it prints please.

Comment: Hi @blackapps , thank you for responding.
1) I'm sending a numpy array of a jpg. The jpg has indeed a resolution of 10x10, thus it's an array of 10 columns and 10 rows. Each column-array combination contains BGR values.
2) I'm not sure whether I should use base 64 to decode, I don't fully understand why that should be done. To be frank I just copied it from the internet.
3)I accidentally wrote javascript instead of java
4)I'll try System.out.println(s); in a few hours.
I appreciate the comments and questions.

Comment: `I'm sending a numpy array of a jpg.` Sorry, i have no idea what that would be. Or you send a .jpg file.  Or not. Jpg files have co rows or colums. Or arrays. So first tell if you send a .jpg file or not.

Comment: Further: You only have to base64 decode if you send stuff base64 encoded.

Comment: Do you even need `s` and `x` ?? have you try to decode `readBuf` directly ?? `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuf, 0, readBuf.length)`

Comment: [[  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]
  [  0 106 254]]

10 of these are being sent within a matrix from Python. This is the image in a numpy array.
I should probably get rid of base64 then.

@MuhammadRio That's what i tried initially, but the messages are the same as previously described: null and unimplemented.

Comment: Sorry that array is sent 30 times, not 10.

Comment: @blackapps the message consists of 

j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j���j

and


������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

when i print s

Comment: BitmapFactory cannot decode those values. I wonder why you send such an array. Why dont you send a .jpg file? If you want to keep the sending side as is then create at receiving side an empty bitmap of 10x10 and convert your colors to pixels.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for helping me! You pointed me in the right direction! Sending a numpy array like that doesn't work, and if it does I've no idea how to decrypt it.

I converted the image to a base64 file in Python before sending it. 
In Java I used the same as it is right now and it worked! My image is being displayed.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!